# How to get the coordinates of the point of a line segment

Tags: coordinate-systems

I have the coordinates of the 2 end points **a** and **b** thanks to which I can draw a line. How can I get the coordinates of all the points of the segment of line starting from point **a** to point **b** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let **a**$(p,q)$, **b**$(r,s)$. Then, what you want is 
$$((1-t)p+tr,(1-t)q+ts)$$
where $t$ is a real number such that $0\le t\le 1$.

Setting $t=0$ gives you **a** and setting $t=1$ gives you **b**.

Comment: how can I know the value of `t` of each point of the segment ?

Comment: @Begueradj: If you choose a real number $t$ such that $0\le t\le 1$, then you can get a coordinate on the line segment.

Comment: So the number of points between `a` and `b` is infinite ?

Comment: @Begueradj: Yes, it is infinite.

Answer (score 0):

While iterpreting $\mathbf a$ and $\mathbf b$ as vectors, if you choose a $t$ between $0$ and $1$, and enter it into
$$t\cdot\mathbf a +(1-t)\cdot\mathbf b$$
it will give you the coordinates of all the points on the line segment.

Comment: @Begueradj Of course. It is called a _parameter_. You chose one of the valid values, like $0.25097$, and you enter it into the equation I wrote above, and once you've calculated it, you get a coordinate for a point on the segment.

Comment: I upvoted on your answer but I accept the one of the user above. In fact your answers are the same,   Hope you're not mad sir.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the coordinates then you can get the equation of the line passing through those 2 points by finding the slope and writing the equation with respect to one of the coordinates.